# How to setup Apache Wink Client keystore and truststore

Tags: java, ssl, keystore, truststore, apache-wink

How do I set a client side keystore and truststore in an Apache Wink Client

I cannot find any documentation on how to do it.

http://wink.apache.org/documentation/1.2.1/Apache_Wink_User_Guide.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think the "usual" code initializing the `SSLContext` will work.

Example how to load the truststore:

```
String path = ....
char[] password = ....
KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(path), password );
TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
tmf.init(keyStore);
SSLContext ctx = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
ctx.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
```

If you also need a keystore for client certificate, use the KeyStoreFactory in a similar way or implement a `KeyManager`

Comment: Did I not need to add the KeyStore and TrustStore to ClientConfig like the Jersey Client?

// import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.ClientConfig;
// import com.sun.jersey.api.client.config.DefaultClientConfig;
ClientConfig config = new DefaultClientConfig();

// import com.sun.jersey.client.urlconnection.HTTPSProperties        config.getProperties().put(HTTPSProperties.PROPERTY_HTTPS_PROPERTIES, new HTTPSProperties(getHostnameVerifier(), getSSLContext()));

Comment: As far as I remember, Wink by default uses HttpsURLConnection, which means that the default SSLContext will be used.

Comment: You can configure Wink to use the Apache HTTP Client, in this case you need to pass the SSL configuration to the client

Comment: I got this working with 

org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient
org.apache.wink.client.httpclient.ApacheHttpClientConfig

But I have to set the https port:
httpClient.getConnectionManager().getSchemeRegistry().register(new Scheme("https", 9443, socketFactory));

Anyway to avoid having to do this each time as I won't know the port before hand